# Отловить время выключения компьютера

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как можно получить в делфи время выключения ПК? Именно в этот момент выключения.

Comment: @LaNC1LoT GetSystemMetrics($2000) тоже не работает?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Пардон) $2000 работает. Это я там по коду уже накуралесил. Сейчас включу виртуалку и посмотрю. Отловило или нет.

Comment: Правьте вопрос, отмечайте решением. А то остальные "специалисты" ответ сейчас снесут, потому что это - якобы не решение.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69300/discussion-on-question-by-lanc1lot----).

Answer (score 5):

`GetSystemMetrics(SM_SHUTTINGDOWN)` в отдельном потоке - не оно ли?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69301/discussion-on-answer-by------).